# How does an inverted person in the movie Tenet see stuff?

Tags: tenet

How do inverted people in the movie Tenet see stuff? Light rays from objects need to enter the eye. But from the inverted person's POV, light rays move out of their eyes?

Comment: Just let science sleep in this case